# Get the span element next to the current span with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
    <span class="mention-persons">
     <span class="link-text" id="parent4a275ca0-1bbd-11e4-8b7c-a02bb830bf59">
      <span class="and_text"></span>&nbsp;Elephant Melephant<span onclick="deletemention(this);" id="4a275ca0-1bbd-11e4-8b7c-a02bb830bf59" class="delete-tag">×</span>&nbsp;
     </span>
    <span class="link-text" id="parent5991dff0-1bcf-11e4-908f-a02bb830bf59">
      <span class="and_text">and</span>&nbsp;Dogs Cats<span onclick="deletemention(this);" id="5991dff0-1bcf-11e4-908f-a02bb830bf59" class="delete-tag">×</span>&nbsp;
    </span>
   </span>
```

Is it possible if i am at at the first `link-text` or at first `and_text` or at first `delete-tag` element i can get the next `and-text` element using jquery and set it text to empty?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please include that in the question.

Comment: I was doing something like $(ele).next('.and_text').text('');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're at the first `link-text`:

   `$(this).next('.link-text').children('.and_text').empty();`
2. If you are at the first `.link-text` or `.delete-tag` use:

   `$(this).closest('.link-text').next('.link-text').children('.and_text').empty();`
3. **UPDATE**

Irrespective of where you are on the first `.link-text`, you can use the following:

```
  var that = $(this).is('.link-text') ? $('.link-text') : $(this).closest('.link-text');
  that.next('.link-text').children('.and_text').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(this).parents(".link-test").next(".link-text").children(".and_text").text('');
```